# Mongoose - findOneAndUpdate callback returns undefind

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, mongoose, return

I have this code:

```
function incrementarValor (sequenceName){
  contador.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: sequenceName},
    {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
    {new:true},
    function(err, valor){
        return valor.sequence_value;
    })}
```

I need this function returns a value of a document, when I test it ,if i try to print, it works but when i try to returns the function give me a  undefind

someone know what is happening?

Comment: You question is confused, and it's missing part of code (contador.findOneAndUpdate ???). Try to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contador.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: sequenceName }, { $inc:{sequence_value:1} }, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // we have the updated user returned to us
  contador.log(user);
```

please note that the update method doesn't return the document. The update statement only return an acknowledgement.